# Alignment's \author

Tags: positioning, titles

How I can put authors in list form.

```
\author{ aaaaa \and bbbb \and ccc }
```

Ok, but the names appear on the same line and I want to display them **vertically**.

Comment: Can you give a visual example of what you are after?

Comment: Check the `authblk` package. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: How about `\author{ aaaaa \\ bbbb \\ ccc }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to preamble

```
\usepackage[options]{authblk}
```

The `authblk` package has options that you can see there: [`authblk.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/authblk.pdf)

And you write the author's list so:

```
\author{ Author1 \and Author2 ... }
```

Comment: You might show explicitly what `options` you have used to solve your problem.

Comment: I had not need to use options, but if somebody need to know the options there is link to see available options.